# referencing control IDs from code behind that is in a repeater

Tags: c#, gridview, repeater, code-behind, sqldatasource

This week I had a problem of trying to determine what control to use to be able to display data from multiple data sources in a non-grid looking way.  Thanks to this forum, I have learned that the best way will be to use a Repeater with different controls such as labels and tables inside the repeater.  Not quite sure exactly how I will get it all implemented yet but the first thing I need to learn is how to change the text from the code behind of a table and a Label that I will have inside the repeater.  I have read up and found that the following should work.  but it doesnt.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Repeater1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Label labelCustomerID = (Label)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("labelCustomerID");
                labelCustomerID.Text = "from code Behind";

            }
```

my declarative syntax is this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <hr/>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelCustomerId"  />
            <div style="padding-left:150px">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelCustomerName" />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelCustomerAddress" />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelCityState" />    
            </div>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridViewRecordData">

            </asp:GridView>
            <hr/>
        </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Thanks to EdB I have gotten this far.  Not still sure how I am gonna fill the gridview with one record of data but first things first... I need to be able to change a label's text.  If i can get that done I am sure the rest will fall into place.

Please help me! :)
dell

Comment: can you post all the code of your code-behind file? I think you are referencing the repeater before it is populated.

Comment: Thanks.  That was it.  I didn't realize the you had to bind the data to it before you could get the control name.  Now I do!  ha! thanks.

Comment: I'll go ahead and post the above comment as an answer so the question can be closed. Please mark as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Repeater1.Items.Count - 1; i++) 
        {
            if(Repeater1.Items[i].ItemType == ListItemType.Item || Repeater1.Items[i].ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                Label labelCustomerID = (Label)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("labelCustomerID"); 
                labelCustomerID.Text = "from code Behind"; 
            }

        }
```

Comment: With the code you gave me I get the following error: Error 9 'object' does not contain a definition for 'FindControl' and no extension method 'FindControl' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Thanks.  and i am sorry to bug you. No errors but as debugging, logic never gets into the for loop.  The reason is because Repeater1.Items.Count is equal to 0 on page load.  Should I take the minus 1 out???

Comment: Never mind.  I took the minus 1 out and I get an index out of range on the IF statement.  I am doing something way wrong.  It should be easier than this to be able to change a controls text inside a repeater.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referencing the repeater before it is populated.